# Prove that $h(x)= f(x) - g(x)$ is even degree

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

If $f$, $g$ are polynomial functions such that $f(x) = g(x)$ and $f''(x) = g''(x)$ have no real roots

i) Prove that $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$ is a polynomial of even degree

ii) $f'(x)= g'(x)$ has exactly one real root

I find it difficult to approach the first question. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Are $f,g$ polynomials of real coefficients?

Comment: @Koro It does not mention , but i guess so

Comment: Hint assuming real coefficients: use the fact that complex roots come in pairs

Comment: @PipiGoss The title (second degree) doesn't match the question (even degree). Anyway, recall that 1) polynomials of odd degree have at least one real root, and 2) between two roots of a polynomial there is a root of its derivative.

Comment: I thought of a solution, suppose that h (x) is an odd polynomial. It follows from the intermediate value theorem that it has at least one real solution. But we have that f(x) = g(x) has no real roots. There we have our contradiction

Comment: @dxiv Thank you sir,  I thought of using Rolle's theorem for the second part

Comment: @PipiGoss That's correct, and you are almost done. Only thing left to add is that $h'$ is a polynomial of odd degree, so it has at least one real root. You just proved it cannot have two, so it must have exactly one.

Comment: @dxiv That's exactly what i thought . Thank you very much for your help and your time!

Comment: Wait, you say $f(x)=g(x)$. That means $h(x)=0$. Is it not $-$ in there?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Presumably the question means that neither $f=g$ nor $f''=g''$ have any real roots.